# How do you launch a Tkinter application from a django website

Tags: django, tkinter

I created a Django website and I want to launch a tkinter program if the user clicks on a button. Can anyone tell me how to do that?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can't do this, unless you're only running django on your local machine.

Comment: @BryanOakley I am trying to do it on my local machine.

Comment: And what tkinter app will do then? It seems that something is wrong with your design in the first place

Comment: I should have been more clear: django needs to be running on your machine and the user also needs to be on your machine. If you call any GUI program from django, it's only going to appear on the monitor attached to that machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, websites cannot cause other programs on the user's computer to run just by clicking a button on a webpage. The next-best thing is a specialized  link that the client understands is associated with another installed application. See: [How can I launch my windows app when a users opens a url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5006486/how-can-i-launch-my-windows-app-when-a-users-opens-a-url)

If you happen to be running the django *server* on the same local system AND is running in the foreground by the same currently logged in user, you *could* also invoke a GUI program this way, as well for example using `subprocess` or `os.system`. Though, this would be quite an odd way to do this.

```py
def my_view():  # Technically works, but in very limited practical use cases.
    subprocess.Popen(['python', 'my-tk-app.py'])
```

Because tkinter also doesn't like to be run in any other thread besides the main thread, and other event loop-related issues, it's not really practical to invoke a tkinter app directly from a Django view, which usually will be running in a separate thread and needs to not be blocked.

For example, this would ***not*** work:

```py
def my_view():
    root.mainloop() # start the TK app
    # fails because tk only wants to start in the main thread
    # even if TK _could_ start, the view would eventually timeout
```

If you need a local tkinter app to also interface with a django server, you're almost always going to be better off by making your GUI app a *client* of the server -- that is to say, your tkinter app should use HTTP(S) or similar mechanism to communicate with Django.